# Why is RandomVariate of special probability distribution doesn't working in all cases

Tags: random, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I would like to generate a random variates in Mathematica 9 with this distribution:

```
f[tetta_, x_] := ( 4 Csc[tetta/2]^4 Sin[tetta] Sin[2 x] (x Cos[x Sin[tetta/2]] -
     Csc[tetta/2] Sin[x Sin[tetta/2]])^2) / (2 Sin[2 x] (-1 - 2 x^2 + 2 x^4 + 2 x Sin[2 x]) +
     Sin[4 x]);

mydist[x_] := ProbabilityDistribution[f[t, x], {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> x > 0];
```

And it's works well. But in some cases it's doesn't. For example:

```
RandomVariate[mydist[78]]
     (* 0.0354395 *)
RandomVariate[mydist[79]]
```

And for the last one Mathematica gives me:
[image: Hmm...]

The same situation is for other parameter values: for *80.2* RandomVariate is working fine, but not for *80.3*.

Could you help me to understand why is so happens and how is to solve that problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your specification of the pdf, `f` has so many cycles in it for certain values of `x` that Mathematica is unable to verify that you have specified a valid pdf, because it loses too much precision in the integration.

I checked this using a simple `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[tt, m], {tt, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog ->  Text[ToString[NIntegrate[f[ttt, m], {ttt, 0, Pi}]], 
    Scaled[{0.7, 0.8}]]], {m, 1, 100}]
```

And for certain values, including 60.2, I got pictures like this:

[image]

with error messages about "catastrophic loss of precision".

One could try increasing the precision of the integration like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[tt, m], {tt, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> 
   Text[ToString[
     NIntegrate[SetPrecision[f[ttt, m], 45], {ttt, 0, Pi}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 40]], Scaled[{0.7, 0.8}]]], {m, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

You can see that this doesn't integrate to 1 and therefore isn't a valid probability density function for this value of $x$.